# Python Duplicate Removal

Tags: python, csv

I have a question about removing duplicates in Python.  I've read a bunch of posts but have not yet been able to solve it.  I have the following csv file:

**EDIT**

**Input:**

```
ID, Source, 1.A, 1.B, 1.C, 1.D
1, ESPN, 5,7,,,M
1, NY Times,,10,12,W
1, ESPN, 10,,Q,,M
```

**Output should be:**

```
ID, Source, 1.A, 1.B, 1.C, 1.D, duplicate_flag
1, ESPN, 5,7,,,M, duplicate
1, NY Times,,10,12,W, duplicate
1, ESPN, 10,,Q,,M, duplicate 
1, NY Times, 5 (or 10 doesn't matter which one),7, 10, 12, W, not_duplicate
```

In words, if the ID is the same, take values from the row with source "NY Times", if the row with "NY Times" has a blank value and the duplicate row from the "ESPN" source has a value for that cell, take the value from the row with the "ESPN" source.  For outputting, flag the original two lines as duplicates and create a third line.

To clarify a bit further, since I need to run this script on many different csv files with different column headers, I can't do something like:

```
    def main():
        with open(input_csv, "rb") as infile:
            input_fields = ("ID", "Source", "1.A", "1.B", "1.C", "1.D")
            reader = csv.DictReader(infile, fieldnames = input_fields)
            with open(output_csv, "wb") as outfile:
                output_fields = ("ID", "Source", "1.A", "1.B", "1.C", "1.D", "d_flag")
                writer = csv.DictWriter(outfile, fieldnames = output_fields)
                writer.writerow(dict((h,h) for h in output_fields))
                next(reader)
                first_row = next(reader)
                for next_row in reader:
                    #stuff
```

Because I want the program to run on the first two columns independently of whatever other columns are in the table.  In other words, "ID" and "Source" will be in every input file, but the rest of the columns will change depending on the file.

Would greatly appreciate any help you can provide!  FYI, "Source" can only be: NY Times, ESPN, or Wall Street Journal and the order of priority for duplicates is: take NY Times if available, otherwise take ESPN, otherwise take Wall Street Journal.  This holds for every input file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below code reads all of the records into a big dictionary whose keys are their identifiers and whose values are dictionaries mapping source names to entire data rows. Then it iterates through the dictionary and gives you the output you asked for.

```
import csv

header = None
idfld = None
sourcefld = None

record_table = {}

with open('input.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        row = [x.strip() for x in row]

        if header is None:
            header = row
            for i, fld in enumerate(header):
                if fld == 'ID':
                    idfld = i
                elif fld == 'Source':
                    sourcefld = i
            continue

        key = row[idfld]
        sourcename = row[sourcefld]

        if key not in record_table:
            record_table[key] = {sourcename: row, "all_rows": [row]}
        else:
            if sourcename in record_table[key]:
                cur_row = record_table[key][sourcename]
                for i, fld in enumerate(row):
                    if cur_row[i] == '':
                        record_table[key][sourcename][i] = fld
            else:
                record_table[key][sourcename] = row
            record_table[key]["all_rows"].append(row)

print ', '.join(header) + ', duplicate_flag'

for recordid in record_table:
    rowdict = record_table[recordid]

    final_row = [''] * len(header)

    rowcount = len(rowdict)

    for sourcetype in ['NY Times', 'ESPN', 'Wall Street Journal']:
        if sourcetype in rowdict:
            row = rowdict[sourcetype]
            for i, fld in enumerate(row):
                if final_row[i] != '':
                    continue
                if fld != '':
                    final_row[i] = fld

    if rowcount > 1:
        for row in rowdict["all_rows"]:
            print ', '.join(row) + ', duplicate'

    print ', '.join(final_row) + ', not_duplicate'
```

Comment: Thanks for the great answer.  It works very well on the data.  Sorry for the delay in responding, I wanted to work through the code myself to make sure I really understood why it works.  I ran into one issue: If a given row has the same "ID" and "Source" values, then the current script will just take the last occurring row with that particular "ID" and "Source" combination.  Is there a way to tweak the code such that all original lines are copied to the output (with the "duplicate" tag if applicable) AND the "not_duplicate" row gets filled in to avoid the problem mentioned in this comment?

Comment: I'll add a sample data point to the above post as an edit so you can see this more easily.  Thanks so much again! This is really helpful and I learned a good amount re-typing it.

Comment: In the new example above, there are two rows with "ID" = 1 and "SOURCE" = ESPN.  If there is no value for a given column in the "NY Times" row and there is a value in both columns of the "ESPN" rows, it doesn't matter which ESPN row we take it from, just that we are consistent across files.  However, if the "NY Times" row does not have a value for a particular column and one "ESPN" row (ESPN A) does not have a value for that column either, take from the other "ESPN" row (ESPN B).  And, if ESPN A has a value but ESPN B does not, and the "NY Times" row does not, take from ESPN A.

Comment: @user7186 I've amended the code above for you. Look at the edit diff for the changes.

Comment: Thanks! This is a terrific answer.